# Angular translation function gets called infinitely

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loops, data-binding, infinite

I have a function which translates text, it's hooked on all of the text and looks like this

```
$rootScope.getWord = function (key) {
  if (angular.isDefined(Language.dict[key])) {
    return Language.dict[key];
  }
  return key;
};
```

This is how it's hooked up in a view:

```
<h1 style="text-align: center">{{getWord('Name')}}</h1>
```

The problem is it's calling getWord infinite times, even if there's only one instance of getWord per view it still goes into a loop.

The language can be changed anytime.

What am I doing wrong and what's the way to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The binding you use (`{{getWord('Name')}}`) is being evaluated in every single iteration of the digest loop. Multiply this by the amount of `getWord` calls ona  page...

To prevent this, use a "[one-time binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#one-time-binding)":

```
<h1 style="text-align: center">{{::getWord('Name')}}</h1>
```

> An expression that starts with `::` is considered a one-time expression.
>   One-time expressions will stop recalculating once they are stable, which happens after the first digest if the expression result is a non-undefined value.

Since you want to be able to re-bind your texts, you're going to have to do something differently:

```
<h1 style="text-align: center">{{translated.Name}}</h1>
```

Then, in your controller, you will have to fill a `$scope.translated` object with all your translations.
The function that gets the translations can be triggered again, should the language change. Something like:

```
$scope.translate = function(keys){
    someTranslationWebService.get(keys, function(response){
        $scope.translated = response;
    });
};
```

Where `keys` can be an array like:

```
['Name', 'CompanyName', 'Address']
```

`response` should be an object like:

```
{
    "Name": "Recipient's name",
    "CompanyName": "Company name",
    "Address": "Delivery address"
}
```

Another option altogether would be to use the ["angular-translate" library](https://angular-translate.github.io/)

Comment: The language can change anytime, how would I rebind again then?

Comment: You can't. Not with the one-time bindings. I'll see if I can come up with something different.

Comment: I'd say using angular-translate or a stateful filter with a service providing translation is the better option here. (angular-translate provides such a filter)

Comment: @Sosdoc: yea, that's what I use.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use filter instead, for example

```
<h1 style="text-align: center">{{ Name | customFilter}}</h1>
angular.module('yourApp')
  .filter('customFilter', ['Language', function(Language) {
    return function(key) {
      return Language.dict[key] || key;
    };
  }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
 var Language = {dict: {Name: 'Name 1'}};
    $scope.visited = [];
    $rootScope.getWord = function(key) {
        if (angular.isDefined(Language.dict[key])) {
            $scope.visited[key] = Language.dict[key];
            return Language.dict[key];
        }
        $scope.visited[key] = key;
        return key;
    };
```

And

```
<span style="text-align: center">{{visited['Name']?visited['Name']:getWord('Name')}}</span>
```

Just clear out visited object when language changes.

Comment: This isnmt very practical for repeated use.